# Entity Framework One-to-One optional relationship with ForeignKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one

I am developing an Entity Framework Code First Database. I have two classes with a 0..1-0..1 relationship:

```
[Table("VociRicevuta")]
public partial class VoceRicevuta
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [...]

    [ForeignKey("Prestazione")]
    public long? IdPrestazione { get; set; }
    [...]
    public virtual Prestazione Prestazione { get; set; }
}


[Table("Prestazioni")]
public partial class Prestazione
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [...]

    [InverseProperty("Prestazione")]
    public virtual VoceRicevuta VoceRicevuta { get; set; }
}
```

A Prestazione may or not be referenced from a VoceRicevuta, a VoceRicevuta may or not have a Prestazione (notice long? ).

Now, I really can't figure out how to configure the relationship with the FluentAPI. I can't use .Map since i DO HAVE IdPrestazione already on my Entities.

This is what I tried:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<VoceRicevuta>().HasOptional(x => x.Prestazione).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.VoceRicevuta);
```

But this code completely IGNORES my already existent IdPrestazione field and creates a new Prestazione_Id field in the database to create te FK.
I need that "IdPrestazione" for many reasons, including performance.

I tried to modify the migration code produced by migrations (for database creating) but now i'm getting errors of non valid fields ("Prestazione_Id is not a valid Field").

How can I make EF recognise the IdPrestazione property?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, by putting the object inside as a field, EF will do the foreign key relationship for you

```
[Table("VociRicevuta")]
public partial class VoceRicevuta
{
[Key]
public virtual Prestazione { get; set; }
[...]


public long? IdPrestazione { get; set; }
[...]
public virtual Prestazione Prestazione { get; set; }
}


[Table("Prestazioni")]
public partial class Prestazione
{
[Key]
public long Id { get; set; }
[...]

[InverseProperty("Prestazione")]
public virtual VoceRicevuta VoceRicevuta { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this Won't fit my model at all. In fact VoceRicevuta has other optional fields like Prestazione. And your solution would mean that Prestazione would be a Required field: I have specified that a VoceRicevuta MAY NOT reference a Prestazione.

Comment: Then make it nullable, put a ? After the type name

Comment: Yes. And EF throws an exception saying that's no sense to make a nullable of a Reference Type, as I told before.